# How to represent an array of variable nesting depth with d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have a dataset which is an array. the data set is of this structure.`

```
    [{

    "rowLabel": "Alimentary Sytem",
    "values": [{
        "columnLabel": "Microarray",
        "value": "High"
    }, {
        "columnLabel": "IHC",
        "value": "High"
    }],
    "children": [

        {
            "rowLabel": "Stomach",
            "values": [{
                "columnLabel": "Microarray",
                "value": "Moderate"
            }, {
                "columnLabel": "IHC",
                "value": "Moderate"
            }]
        }, {
            "rowLabel": "Mouth",
            "values": [{
                "columnLabel": "Microarray",
                "value": "High"
            }, {
                "columnLabel": "IHC",
                "value": "High"
            }],
            "children": [{
                    "label": "Tongue",
                    "values": [{
                        "columnLabel": "Microarray",
                        "value": "High"
                    }, {
                        "columnLabel": "IHC",
                        "value": "Negative"
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}, {
    "rowLabel": "Muscle",
    "values": [{
        "columnLabel": "Microarray",
        "value": "Low"
    }, {
        "columnLabel": "IHC",
        "value": "Low"
    }],
    "children":[{
            "rowLabel": "tendon",
            "values": [{
                "columnLabel": "Microarray",
                "value": "Moderate"
            }, {
                "columnLabel": "IHC",
                "value": "Moderate"
            }]
        }]

}]
```

`
I would like to  present that in this format using d3.

```html
<ul>
  <li>Alimentry Canal
    <ul>
      <li>Stomach</li>
      <li>Mouth
      <ul>
        <li>Tongue</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Muscles</li>
</ul>
```

I tried doing this using recursive calls on the d3 selections but it keeps telling me groupData not found and ends at the fist level of nesting.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: That data set has a variable degree of depths  as some `children` may have `children` while others don't have. So I wanto be able to do a recursive call on algorith on the data that will touch and represent all `subnodes`

Comment: Do you also need the bullets, and different bullets, or just the indentation?

Comment: I would also like the bullets because i would want to be able to group the subnodes of a parent node and toggle their visibility on click of the parent.

Comment: Please check the update at the bottom. I think that's what you might be looking for? https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for something like the snippet below. Basically what we are doing is:

1. flatten your array and add a `level` property to each of the objects.
2. Create the text for all of them
3. Set indentation based on the level
4. Place them vertically based on their index.

Note that `alignment-base` determines the placement of the text on the line.

Setting it to `hanging` makes that if I set the `y-position` to 0, you will see the text.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#BaselineAlignmentProperties) and you can get a sense of what they look like [here](http://apike.ca/prog_svg_text_style.html)

```js
 var tree = [{

   "rowLabel": "Alimentary Sytem",
   "values": [{
     "columnLabel": "Microarray",
     "value": "High"
   }, {
     "columnLabel": "IHC",
     "value": "High"
   }],
   "children": [

     {
       "rowLabel": "Stomach",
       "values": [{
         "columnLabel": "Microarray",
         "value": "Moderate"
       }, {
         "columnLabel": "IHC",
         "value": "Moderate"
       }]
     }, {
       "rowLabel": "Mouth",
       "values": [{
         "columnLabel": "Microarray",
         "value": "High"
       }, {
         "columnLabel": "IHC",
         "value": "High"
       }],
       "children": [{
         "rowLabel": "Tongue",
         "values": [{
           "columnLabel": "Microarray",
           "value": "High"
         }, {
           "columnLabel": "IHC",
           "value": "Negative"
         }]
       }]
     }
   ]
 }, {
   "rowLabel": "Muscle",
   "values": [{
     "columnLabel": "Microarray",
     "value": "Low"
   }, {
     "columnLabel": "IHC",
     "value": "Low"
   }],
   "children": [{
     "rowLabel": "tendon",
     "values": [{
       "columnLabel": "Microarray",
       "value": "Moderate"
     }, {
       "columnLabel": "IHC",
       "value": "Moderate"
     }]
   }]

 }]


 function flatten(arr, level) {

   return arr.reduce(function(flat, toFlatten) {
     toFlatten.level = level;
     var result = flat.concat(toFlatten);
     if (Array.isArray(toFlatten.children)) {
       result = result.concat(flatten(toFlatten.children, level + 1));
     }
     return result;
   }, []);
 }

var flatTree = flatten(tree, 0);
var indentWidth = 50;
var lineHeight = 20;

var svg = d3.select('#svg').append('svg').attr("width", 200).attr("height", 500).append('g');

var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(flatTree)
            .enter()
            .append('text')
            .text(function(d){ 
              return d.rowLabel; 
            })
            .attr('alignment-baseline', 'hanging')
            .attr('x', function(d){
               return indentWidth * d.level;
            })
            .attr('y', function(d, i){
               return lineHeight * i;
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="svg"></div>
```

---

***UPDATE: *** Given the OP's last comment I think this is the most appropiate solution: [Collapsible Tree](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083).